# Advent of Code 2016: Day 2, Part 1

Tags: programming-challenge, rust

I'm working through [Advent of Code 2016](https://adventofcode.com/2016) in Rust. The prizes go to the swift, but I'm aiming for well-written code. This is [Day 2](https://adventofcode.com/2016/day/2).

To summarize the problem statement, given a newline-separated list of directions (e.g. "ULL\nRRDDD\nLURDL\nUUUUD\n"), move about on a 9-key keypad starting at 5, freely colliding with the edges. On newlines, emit the output. In this case the answer is 1985.

I am using rustc version `1.15.0-nightly (71c06a56a 2016-12-18)`. My code can also be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/matthew-piziak/advent-of-code-2016).

My answer for Day 2 is quite similar to my answer for [Day 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151121/advent-of-code-2016-day-1).

## lib.rs

```
// Activate impl-trait syntax and disable incompatible clippy warning.
#![feature(conservative_impl_trait)]
#![allow(unknown_lints)]
#![allow(needless_lifetimes)]

// Other features
#![feature(try_from)]

mod day_02;

pub fn day_02() {
    let day_02_answer = day_02::code(include_str!("day_02_input"));
    assert_eq!(day_02_answer, Ok("279".into()));
}
```

## day_02.rs

```
use std::convert::TryFrom;

type Error = String;
type Result<T> = ::std::result::Result<T, Error>;

// Keypad structure:
// 1 2 3
// 4 5 6
// 7 8 9
pub fn code(instructions: &str) -> Result<String> {
    use self::Instruction::*;

    let mut code = String::from("");
    let mut curr_key: Key = 5;
    for instruction in Instruction::try_many_from(instructions) {
        let instruction = instruction?;
        let row = (curr_key - 1) / 3;
        let col = (curr_key - 1) % 3;
        match (instruction, row, col) {
            (Up, 0, _) | (Down, 2, _) | (Left, _, 0) | (Right, _, 2) => {}
            (Up, _, _) => {
                curr_key -= 3;
            }
            (Down, _, _) => {
                curr_key += 3;
            }
            (Left, _, _) => {
                curr_key -= 1;
            }
            (Right, _, _) => {
                curr_key += 1;
            }
            (End, _, _) => {
                code.push_str(&format!("{}", curr_key));
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(code)
}

type Key = usize;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Instruction {
    Up,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right,
    End,
}

impl Instruction {
    fn try_many_from<'a>(s: &'a str) -> impl Iterator<Item = Result<Self>> + 'a {
        s.chars().map(Self::try_from)
    }
}

impl TryFrom<char> for Instruction {
    type Err = Error;

    fn try_from(c: char) -> Result<Self> {
        match c {
            'U' => Ok(Instruction::Up),
            'R' => Ok(Instruction::Right),
            'D' => Ok(Instruction::Down),
            'L' => Ok(Instruction::Left),
            '\n' => Ok(Instruction::End),
            invalid => Err(format!("Instruction invalid: {}", invalid)),
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::*;
    use super::Instruction::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_parse_instruction_success() {
        let instruction = Instruction::try_from('U');
        assert_eq!(instruction, Ok(Up));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_parse_instructions_success() {
        let instructions = Instruction::try_many_from("ULRD\nU").collect::<Result<Vec<_>>>();
        assert_eq!(instructions, Ok(vec![Up, Left, Right, Down, End, Up]));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_parse_instruction_invalid() {
        let instruction = Instruction::try_from('x');
        assert_eq!(instruction, Err("Instruction invalid: x".into()));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_parse_instructions_invalid() {
        let instructions = Instruction::try_many_from("ULxDy").collect::<Result<Vec<_>>>();
        assert_eq!(instructions, Err("Instruction invalid: x".into()));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_code() {
        let code = code("ULL\nRRDDD\nLURDL\nUUUUD\n");
        assert_eq!(code, Ok("1985".into()));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_code_advent_input() {
        let day_02_answer = code(include_str!("day_02_input"));
        assert_eq!(day_02_answer, Ok("69642".into()));
    }
}
```

I use `Error = String` instead of `Error = &'static str` because I want to include erroneous instructions in the error message. Is that faulty reasoning?

Comment: Haha, sorry you put a bounty on it as I was typing stuff up <-- embarrassed.

Comment: Have you been doing the second halves of each day, after unlocking the first part?

Comment: The bounty is totally deserved; the answer is great as always. I'll award it in 22 hours when it becomes available. Also, I didn't notice there were second halves! How should I work those in? I think I'll rename days 1 and 2 with "Part 1" and put up "Part 2"  separately. Then for future days I'll probably put them up concurrently.

Comment: I've been taking it as a challenge to try and rework my code so that it can solve both parts with the same code base, which seemed to be a good way of stretching the flexibility part.

Comment: Oh certainly. I'm just wondering what the best way to present it on CodeReview.SX is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### lib.rs

1. The comments on the features have dubious value; they seem to repeat what's already said, or be ultra generic ("other features").
2. I wouldn't broadly disable all unknown lints. Too wide a net for my tastes. [Clippy provides](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy#allowingdenying-lints) a nicer method: only enabling things when `cargo clippy` is running.
3. Likewise, I wouldn't do a package-wide `allow` of the incorrect lints, at least not at first. Just on the particular item. Speaking of which, this would have been a good time to document **why** features / lints were allowed, not that they *were*.

```
#![feature(conservative_impl_trait)]
#![feature(try_from)]

mod day_02;

pub fn day_02() {
    let day_02_answer = day_02::code(include_str!("day_02_input"));
    assert_eq!(day_02_answer, Ok("279".into()));
}
```

### day_02.rs

1. Use `String::new`, not `String::from("")`.
2. Use `write!(&mut string, ...)` instead of allocating a new string with `format!` then re-allocating memory to copy it.

```
use std::convert::TryFrom;
use std::fmt::Write;

type Error = String;
type Result<T> = ::std::result::Result<T, Error>;

// Keypad structure:
// 1 2 3
// 4 5 6
// 7 8 9
pub fn code(instructions: &str) -> Result<String> {
    use self::Instruction::*;

    let mut code = String::new();
    let mut curr_key: Key = 5;
    for instruction in Instruction::try_many_from(instructions) {
        let instruction = instruction?;
        let row = (curr_key - 1) / 3;
        let col = (curr_key - 1) % 3;
        match (instruction, row, col) {
            (Up, 0, _) | (Down, 2, _) | (Left, _, 0) | (Right, _, 2) => {}
            (Up, _, _) => {
                curr_key -= 3;
            }
            (Down, _, _) => {
                curr_key += 3;
            }
            (Left, _, _) => {
                curr_key -= 1;
            }
            (Right, _, _) => {
                curr_key += 1;
            }
            (End, _, _) => {
                write!(&mut code, "{}", curr_key).expect("Unable to append to string");
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(code)
}

type Key = usize;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Instruction {
    Up,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right,
    End,
}

impl Instruction {
    #[cfg_attr(feature = "cargo-clippy", allow(needless_lifetimes))]
    fn try_many_from<'a>(s: &'a str) -> impl Iterator<Item = Result<Self>> + 'a {
        s.chars().map(Self::try_from)
    }
}

impl TryFrom<char> for Instruction {
    type Err = Error;

    fn try_from(c: char) -> Result<Self> {
        match c {
            'U' => Ok(Instruction::Up),
            'R' => Ok(Instruction::Right),
            'D' => Ok(Instruction::Down),
            'L' => Ok(Instruction::Left),
            '\n' => Ok(Instruction::End),
            invalid => Err(format!("Instruction invalid: {}", invalid)),
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::*;
    use super::Instruction::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_parse_instruction_success() {
        let instruction = Instruction::try_from('U');
        assert_eq!(instruction, Ok(Up));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_parse_instructions_success() {
        let instructions = Instruction::try_many_from("ULRD\nU").collect::<Result<Vec<_>>>();
        assert_eq!(instructions, Ok(vec![Up, Left, Right, Down, End, Up]));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_parse_instruction_invalid() {
        let instruction = Instruction::try_from('x');
        assert_eq!(instruction, Err("Instruction invalid: x".into()));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_parse_instructions_invalid() {
        let instructions = Instruction::try_many_from("ULxDy").collect::<Result<Vec<_>>>();
        assert_eq!(instructions, Err("Instruction invalid: x".into()));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_code() {
        let code = code("ULL\nRRDDD\nLURDL\nUUUUD\n");
        assert_eq!(code, Ok("1985".into()));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_code_advent_input() {
        let day_02_answer = code(include_str!("day_02_input"));
        assert_eq!(day_02_answer, Ok("69642".into()));
    }
}
```

---

It's an interesting decision to parse `\n` as an `Instruction`. It kind of fits well with the domain, as you could liken it to hitting the "Enter" key on the keypad. However, the choice of newline seems incidental. If they wanted a key, I would have expected it to have a dedicated letter in the input file.

Additionally, hard-coding `\n` ties you to a specific platform's newline convention. This code won't work with Windows-style newlines.